# ERROR #11321 PLUGIN "gatsby-source-strapi" gives error while running the sourceNodes. gatsby develop runs successfully but gatsby build fails

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi, gatsby-source-graphql

ERROR #11321  API.NODE.EXECUTION

"gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Request failed with status code 404

AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404

- settle.js:19 settle
  [FEtest]/[gatsby-source-strapi]/[axios]/lib/core/settle.js:19:12
- http.js:570 IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd
  [FEtest]/[gatsby-source-strapi]/[axios]/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11
- node:events:526 IncomingMessage.emit
  node:events:526:35
- readable:1359 endReadableNT
  node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12
- task_queues:82 processTicksAndRejections
  node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21

error #11321 api.node.execution "gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourcenodes lifecycle: request failed with status code 404 axioserror: request failed with status code 404

**gatsby.-config.js** file

{
resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
options: {
apiURL: `http://localhost:1337`,
queryLimit: 1000, // Default to 100
collectionTypes: [`hello`],
token: 'mytoken'
},
}